# FedProx with TensorFlow Federated

Tags: tensorflow-federated

Would anyone know how to implement the FedProx optimisation algorithm with TensorFlow Federated? The only implementation that seems to be available online was developed directly with TensorFlow. A TFF implementation would enable an easier comparison with experiments that utilise FedAvg which the framework supports.

This is the link to the FedProx repo: https://github.com/litian96/FedProx

Link to the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.06127

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, FedProx implementation is not available. I agree it would be a valuable algorithm to have.

If you are interested in contributing FedProx, the best place to start would be [`simple_fedavg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/v0.14.0/tensorflow_federated/python/research/simple_fedavg) which is a minimal implementation of FedAvg meant as a starting point for extensions -- see the readme there for more details.

I think the major change would need to happen to the [`client_update`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/v0.14.0/tensorflow_federated/python/research/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L185) method, where you would add the proximal term depending on `model_weights` and `initial_weights` to the loss computed in forward pass.

Comment: I would like to know whether adding the following lines (right after `client_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_weights.trainable))`) in `client_update` would work to implement FedProx starting from `simple_fedavg`:


 `prox_term = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b:  (-1)*mu*(a - b), model_weights.trainable, initial_weights.trainable)` and 


`client_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(prox_term,  model_weights.trainable))`


Considering the `tf.keras.optimizers.SGD` as `client_optimizer`.
I know that implementing a custom Optimizer would be more elegant though.

Comment: Probably yes, hard to really know without proper example though. But it may be better and more general to add the prox term to the loss, and let `tf.GradientTape` deal with it.

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestions (thank you!). I reported my implementation in another answer of this post.

Answer (score 1):

I provide below my implementation of FedProx in TFF. I am not 100% sure that this is the right implementation; I post this answer also for discussing on actual code example.

I tried to follow the suggestions in the Jacub Konecny's answer and comment.

Starting from the `simple_fedavg` (referring to the TFF Github repo), I just modified the `client_update` method, and specifically changing the input argument for calculating the gradient with the `GradientTape`, i.e. instaead of just passing in input the `outputs.loss`, the tape calculates the gradient considering the `outputs.loss` + `proximal_term` previosuly (and iteratively) calculated.

```py
@tf.function
def client_update(model, dataset, server_message, client_optimizer):
"""Performans client local training of "model" on "dataset".Args:
model: A "tff.learning.Model".
dataset: A "tf.data.Dataset".
server_message: A "BroadcastMessage" from server.
client_optimizer: A "tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer". 
Returns:
A "ClientOutput".
""" 

def difference_model_norm_2_square(global_model, local_model):
    """Calculates the squared l2 norm of a model difference (i.e.
    local_model - global_model)
    Args:
        global_model: the model broadcast by the server
        local_model: the current, in-training model

    Returns: the squared norm

    """
    model_difference = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                           local_model,
                                           global_model)
    squared_norm = tf.square(tf.linalg.global_norm(model_difference))
    return squared_norm

model_weights = model.weights
initial_weights = server_message.model_weights
tf.nest.map_structure(lambda v, t: v.assign(t), model_weights,
                     initial_weights)

num_examples = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
loss_sum = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)
# Explicit use `iter` for dataset is a trick that makes TFF more robust in
# GPU simulation and slightly more performant in the unconventional usage
# of large number of small datasets.

for batch in iter(dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        outputs = model.forward_pass(batch)

        # ------ FedProx ------
        mu = tf.constant(0.2, dtype=tf.float32)
        prox_term =(mu/2)*difference_model_norm_2_square(model_weights.trainable, initial_weights.trainable)
        fedprox_loss = outputs.loss + prox_term

    # Letting GradientTape dealing with the FedProx's loss
    grads = tape.gradient(fedprox_loss, model_weights.trainable)

    client_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model_weights.trainable))

    batch_size = tf.shape(batch['x'])[0]
    num_examples += batch_size
    loss_sum += outputs.loss * tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)

weights_delta = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                      model_weights.trainable,
                                      initial_weights.trainable)
client_weight = tf.cast(num_examples, tf.float32)
return ClientOutput(weights_delta, client_weight, loss_sum / client_weight)
```

Comment: Looks good, you may also consider `tf.linalg.global_norm` to simplify the new part.